# Render list with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to render a dynamic list but inside the jsx rendered, I can't display any item this is my code, I've also tried with useState `const [orderList, setOrderList] = useState([])` and `setOrderList(prev => [...prev, childData])` but it returns me an empty array so I've opted for the classic javascript way but it won't work, it also won't console log the data inside the render

```
const OrdiniModuloVideoAds = () => {
    let orderList = [];

    const ordiniRef = ref(realtimeDatabase, "ordinazioneVideoAds/modulo/ordini");

    useEffect(() => {
        onValue(ordiniRef, (snapshot) => {
            snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
                const childData = childSnapshot.val();
                orderList.push(childData);
            });
            console.log(orderList);
        });
    }, []);

    return (
        <StyledOrdiniModuloVideoAds>
            <div className='ordiniWrapper'>
                {orderList.map((i) => {
                    return (
                        <span>{i.mail}</span>
                    );
                })}
            </div>
        </StyledOrdiniModuloVideoAds>
    );
};
```

**EDIT**
This is the snippet with the useState:

```
const OrdiniModuloVideoAds = () => {
    const [orderList, setOrderList] = useState([])

    const ordiniRef = ref(realtimeDatabase, "ordinazioneVideoAds/modulo/ordini");

    useEffect(() => {
        onValue(ordiniRef, (snapshot) => {
            snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
                const childData = childSnapshot.val();
                setOrderList((prev) => [...prev, childData])
            });
            console.log(orderList);
        });
    }, []);

    return (
        <StyledOrdiniModuloVideoAds>
            <div className='ordiniWrapper'>
                {orderList.map((i) => {
                    return (
                        <span>{i.mail}</span>
                    );
                })}
            </div>
        </StyledOrdiniModuloVideoAds>
    );
};
```

The data is actually added because it logs to me the array on the useEffect Any suggestion?

Comment: can you show us the implementation that you have done with useState?

Comment: Bro, you can't render your list with a standard javascript! Let me create a solution try that code and let me know if that code works for you or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution hopefully it will fix your issue.

```
const OrdiniModuloVideoAds = () => {
    const [orderList, setOrderList] = React.useState([]);

    const ordiniRef = ref(realtimeDatabase, "ordinazioneVideoAds/modulo/ordini");

    useEffect(() => {
        onValue(ordiniRef, (snapshot) => {
            snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
                const childData = childSnapshot.val();
                setOrderList(prev => ([...prev, childData])); /// Order list array is empty because you're not returning the data properly that's why it just gives you the default empty array in the console.
            });
        });
    }, []);

    return (
        <StyledOrdiniModuloVideoAds>
            <div className='ordiniWrapper'>
                {orderList.map((i) => <span key={i.mail}>{i.mail}</span>)}
            </div>
        </StyledOrdiniModuloVideoAds>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because your map callback does not return anything:

```
<div className='ordiniWrapper'>
  {array.map((i) => {
    return (
     <span>{i.mail}</span>
    );
  })}
</div>
```

Or the short version:

```
<div className='ordiniWrapper'>
  {array.map((i) => (
    <span>{i.mail}</span>
  ))}
</div>
```

Comment: You are right. But I don't think updating the array directly by its ref is a good practice. He should use useState instead.

Comment: Sorry I've forgot to add it, it also doesn't work with the return